# C# access to the path is denied...(System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\' is denied.)

Tags: c#, file

I have a problem with my c# program.

When I try to create a file, the program throws a exception:

> the acces to the path is denied (System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:' is denied.

This is the code who create the file:

```
static void crate()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specify the path where the file will be created");
        string pathc = Console.ReadLine();//ask the path
        if (pathc != "stop")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now specify the file name ");
            string wathc = Console.ReadLine();//ask the file name for the new file
            if (wathc != "stop")
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(pathc))//check if the path exist
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SPECIFY THE CONTENT OF FILE!");
                    string modify = Console.ReadLine();//the content of the file
                    if(modify != "stop")
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(pathc,modify);/here there is a exception
                        Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
                        File.Move(pathc, wathc);
                        beggining();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        beggining();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The specified path doesn't exist\n");
                    beggining();
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                beggining();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            beggining();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NO! the file maybe exist....retry please ex:C:/p.txt ({0})\n", e.GetBaseException());
        beggining();
    }    
}
```

Comment: on windows you need administrator rights to modify files in C:\. Try starting your programm with admin rights or (better) use a different location.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you are calling `beggining();` in every possible scenario, why not just call it at the end of your routine instead of spamming those else blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with the file С:\Test\p.txt or D:\Test\p.txt

Answer (score 0):

In the line `File.WriteAllText(pathc,modify);` you try to write to the definite file, but it looks like var `pathc` was initialized with path only (e.g. `E:\`).
I would suggest using

```
wathc = Path.Combine(pathc, wathc); 
File.WriteAllText(wathc, modify);
Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
beggining();
```

the line `File.Move(pathc, wathc);` should be removed because you already have the file with right filename and needed context.

Comment: Yes thanks!It work! the acces of the root is just denied.....but the access to other paths is not denied but i have a DirectoryNotFoundException.....And i writed E:/test/

Comment: Which line gives you `DirectoryNotFoundException`? `Directory.Exists` condition should check for this (and it checks).

Answer (score 0):

Normally C drive's access is denied.
If you want to still access the C: Drive then change the ownership to everyone by seeing this reference.
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-change-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/