# Unable to Save all the elements of a List to a text file

Tags: c#, generics, file-io, streamwriter.write

I am trying to save all the contents of a List into a text file but I am unable to do . Below is the code that I have tried

```
 // here is my list type 
 List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

 //code below for saving the contents of the list into text file 
 string file = @"C:\Users\textWriter.txt";
        // check if the file exists
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
            else
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(@"SavedList.txt"))
                {
                    foreach (String s in list2)
                        tw.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Op)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Op.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving lists to txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300572/saving-lists-to-txt-file)

Comment: Have you tried `File.WriteAllText()`?

Comment: If the file exists your code only deletes it but do no generates a new one. Remove the else statement.

Comment: Why not `File.WriteAllLines(file, list2)`? It will also recreate that file if it exists.

Comment: @gunr2171 , Sir i am not getting any error or exceptions .

Comment: @gunr2171 , I have already gone through the link you provide sir but I am unable to understand what is "Lists.verbList " in that code

Comment: If your looking for the file savedlist.txt - it will be in your bin\debug folder

Comment: Based on @McNets's comment, you have a typo with your if/else statement. But please read the rest of my first comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened?

Comment: @gunr2171 as suggested by duerzd96 , I have found the file but it is blank .

Comment: because there is nothing in your list.  try adding List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" }; to your code to replace your list just temporarily

Comment: When you walk through the code with breakpoints, does it run the code to write lines to the text file at all (`tw.WriteLine(s)`)? How many entries are in `list2`? Does the file exist when the if statement is ran?

Comment: @gunr2171 , I have double check my list . It has 95 elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what is the exception but i strongly recommend to use this instead:

```
File.WriteAllLines(file, list2);
```

If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Documentation: [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-6.0)

---

In your code you are using different paths, maybe that's the reason

Comment: Now I am getting the error that the access to the path is denied but I am the administrator.                                     string file = @"C:\Users\textWriter.txt";
            // check if the file exists
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(file))
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllLines(file, list2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Op)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Op.Message);
            }

Answer (score 0):

You have different pathes in (File.Exists(file) and File.CreateText(@"SavedList.txt").
Next, did u add elements in List?

Comment: string file = @"C:\Users\textWriter.txt";
            // check if the file exists
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(file))
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllLines(file, list2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Op)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Op.Message);
            }

Comment: now the error is coming that that access is denied

Comment: I tried op code and it worked for me - maybe better ways to do it but ops real problem was that there was nothing in list.

Comment: U can receive this error if the file is opened or path is system like "Program Files"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. With my updated code as suggested by @Tim Schmelter and from the help by this link [C# access to the path is denied...(System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\' is denied.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423409/c-sharp-access-to-the-path-is-denied-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-acce), I now can see the file with all the contents written to it.

```
 string file = @"D:\textWriter.txt";
        // check if the file exists
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(file, list2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Op)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Op.Message);
        }
```